# How to create two seperate arrays from 2 separate ID's using PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I create two arrays from MySQL database? I would like to use id 1 for my first array and id 2 for my second array. My goal was to create two arrays and make a separate array from the duplicates.

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$var1 = '1';
$var2 = '2';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=$var1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            $a1 = $row["a1"];
            $a2 = $row["a2"];
            $a3 = $row["a3"];
            $a4 = $row["a4"];

            $b1 = $row["a4"];
            $b2 = $row["a4"];
            $b3 = $row["a4"];
            $b4 = $row["a4"];

    }

    $array1 = array($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4);
    $array2 = array($b1, $b2, $b3, $b4);
    $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

echo implode(" ",$array1);
echo "<br>";
echo implode(" ",$array2);
echo "<br>";
echo implode(" ",$result);

} else {
    echo "0 results";
} 
$conn->close();  
?>
```

Comment: What should happen if you'd have a 3rd row (for id=3): 7 2 6 4 ? And a 4th row, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the resolution for ID value of 2 there is no need to change the `$result` variable name, but it should be done anyway just to make it more friendly.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$var1 = '1';
$var2 = '2';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=$var1 OR id=$var2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($row['id'] == $var1){
            $a1 = $row['a1'];
            $a2 = $row['a2'];
            $a3 = $row['a3'];
            $a4 = $row['a4'];
        } else if($row['id'] == $var2){
            $b1 = $row['a1'];
            $b2 = $row['a2'];
            $b3 = $row['a3'];
            $b4 = $row['a4'];
        }
    }
    $array1 = array($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4);
    $array2 = array($b1, $b2, $b3, $b4);
    $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

    echo implode(' ', $array1);
    echo '<br>';
    echo implode(' ', $array2);
    echo '<br>';
    echo implode(' ', $result);
} else {
    echo '0 results';
} 
$conn->close();  
?>
```

Comment: Remember not to change the variable name everywhere, and only _inside_ the while loop. In other words, you should _only_ change the name 2 times: when using `array_intersect` and `print_r`. If this is what you did, then what variable name did you use? And do you get the exact same error on line 7?

Comment: Oh, that, you're right, I forgot to provide a solution for that part, I only corrected the fatal error. I'll edit it to show you one possible way. Hang on.

Comment: There you go, that should work. Sorry for not addressing the question, I got carried away by the fatal error!

Comment: But this will only work for those static numbers... if you want it to be dynamic... then a lot more editing should be done! But I believe that will do what you expect for now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, please do remember what I said about dynamic values, you might need the use of a good parameterized statement which will also add security and efficiency to your code. Don't forget to accept the answer (maybe consider upvoting) and happy coding!

Comment: Just to follow up since the question is still open, do you need anything else? Is it working now?

Comment: @ApexCapstone If Zeke's solution answers your question, then you should mark it as "accepted", so that other users can benefit from it too.

Comment: @ApexCapstone I don’t mean to be annoying, but we’re here to help you so if your question wasn’t answered, then let us know what else we can do, or else accept an answer or delete your question. People seeking answers need to know what’s the correct answer, it’s not only about you but whoever visits this page in the future hoping to find help.

Comment: @ApexCapstone I'm not interested in the points, but I am concerned about your question not being answered yet. It doesn't seem to be a bad question at all, I most certainly did not downvote it. Maybe it's because there is an obvious and easy way to generalize the code for infinite `id`s but you were still asking to get the result based on `id`s 1 and 2 specifically. Plus, using parameterized statements would be very interesting. All I'm here for is to help askers like you, and all other people who ghost questions daily in search for answers. That's why I follow up open questions I've answered.